# Design help needed

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, visitor-pattern

I have a model call Drug

```
class Drug{

String drugId;
String name;
String strength;
}
```

this interface takes a drugId and returns the Drug Model

```
interface IProcessor{
getDrug(String drugId)
}
```

// easy flow

```
class ProcessorA extends IProcessor{
protected Drug getDrug(String drugId){
  //get Drug from source A
  return Drug
}
}
```

// From source B, I will be getting additional fields. Am not sure how i can append the new fields
to the drug Model

```
class ProcessorB extends IProcessor{
protected Drug getDrug(String drugId){
//get Drug from source B
// Add few more fields specific to B 
  return Drug
}
}
```

1) Extend the Drug model (class DrugB extends Drug) for ProcessorB and add the new fields. In this case, I might be ending up typecasting the DrugB. Is this ok?

2) Add the common fields to Drug Class and use it. This is fine, but number of fields for each type of processor could be increasing.

Is there any patterns I should be thinking of. Please advice.

Comment: You tagged the Visitor Pattern. Why don't you just use it?

Comment: is that the only option. could you please post a code snippet for the above sample. I see lot of samples online, but i think i will understand better for the problem i face. Thank you

Comment: Patterns should be applied relative to your understanding and not used because many see them as a best practice. Experiment with a side project.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you are trying to append the fields to the Drug model object so this logically rules out the subclassing.
If you would like to give a structure to the values returned by a processor
then you can create a new structure DrugB and DrugC and make these structures as part of the original Drug object.
This kind of segregation will make the ProcessorA to return a DrugA kind of object and ProcessorB to...and so on and so forth.
So Drug class will have DrugB and DrugC as objects within it.
This is one way of looking at it.

Comment: That is a good option. But if I need to add new fields say DrugD,DrugE etc.. each time I have to change the Drug class  to add the setters DrugD and DrugE.

Comment: DrugD and DrugE are not fields they are separate class structures that would come into existence when you have new processors returning a new section of information pertaining to the Drug schema